# Order of radio button events in C#

Tags: c#, events, radio-button

I have some radio buttons on a form. When a user changes the radio button selection, I update another object with that info. Each of the radio buttons has a different event handler, but all of them are for the CheckedChanged event.

Which event is fired first? The CheckedChanged from the radio button that is **losing selection**, or the CheckedChanged from the radio button that is **being selected**? Or is it a race?

Comment: Great question! I actually don't know, but I would only trigger on the "true" value just to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes one minute to create a new WinForms project, drag two radiobuttons on it and assigning two separate event handlers to their CheckedChanged events. So the answer is, in this case: uncheck fires first.

However, it is [not documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkedchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so it could change with any .NET update (unlikely, but still). Don't bind your application logic to it.

If you could explain your actual problem, your question can be answered more specifically. I guess your code looks something like this:

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SomeLabel.Text = "Option 1";
}

private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SomeLabel.Text = "Option 2";
}
```

Change it to take in account the state of the radiobutton:

```
if ((sender as RadioButton).Checked)
{
    SomeLabel.Text = "Option 1";
}
```

So your code doesn't depend on the order of the events anymore and doesn't execute when it's actually not required.

Comment: Out of curiosity, was this true regardless of which radio button was selected?

Comment: Thanks, I did test this quite a bit, and the code we have works in the manner you describe. But since race conditions don't present obviously (and often not at all on the same machine) even with multiple tests, I was hoping someone could find this documented. Since the application logic is currently bound to this, I'll be refactoring the code.

Comment: @Freefall given the nature of radiobuttons it seems logical, however I can't find an MSDN resource that ensures this behavior. Does the edit (`if ((sender as RadioButton).Checked)`) help?

Comment: Oh absolutely, and that's what I'll do. I just didn't want to go ripping apart (seemingly) working code if MS had documented the order.